# "invalid input syntax for integer" when input is actually a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to extract an email from Basic Auth string like this:

```
SELECT substring(decode(substring('"authorization":["Basic dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=="]', '(?<="Basic ).*?(?="])'), 'base64'), '^.*(?=:)');
```

Expected result is `test@test.com`, however I'm getting an error instead:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "^.*(?=:)"
```

What's the problem here? Does postgres think that `substring` second argument must be an integer for some reason?

EDIT: Simplified this query a little just to demo that decoding is working:

```
SELECT decode(substring('"authorization":["Basic dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=="]', '(?<="Basic ).*?(?="])'), 'base64');
```

result: `test@test.com:password`

EDIT2: To people pointing out the absence of `from` - according to postgres docs you don't need it and it's interchangeable with a comma in this case - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html

Example from this page:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('XY1234Z', 'Y*([0-9]{1,3})');
Result: 123
```

EDIT3: Spelling.

Comment: What else should it be???

Comment: Uh..yeah.  https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php

Comment: Haha .... Caballero .... a horse with no name.  Perfect.

Comment: @jarlh it should produce expected result and not throw an error.

Comment: @rory.ap according to postgres documentation `substring()` function also takes regural expression as an argument.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're getting from that link in `EDIT2`. The word is `comma`, not `coma`, and in neither case does that word appear at all in that linked page.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for pointing out the typo, problem now solved - answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `convert_from` to change the `decode` output to `utf-8` or any other encoding format.

The output of decode is set of integer, not `test..`, hence the error.

http://rextester.com/NTMHG12543

```
SELECT substring(convert_from(decode(substring('"authorization":["Basic dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=="]', '(?<="Basic ).*?(?="])'
                                              ), 'base64'
                                    ), 'utf-8'
                             ), '^.*(?=:)'
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that result of decode is not a text. It is a bytea and then substring expects an integer, not a regular expression. Just change type of the result of decode to text and all works perfectly (i hope so)

```
SELECT substring((decode(substring('"authorization":["Basic dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=="]', '(?<="Basic ).*?(?="])'), 'base64'))::text ,'^.*(?=:)');
```

Comment: I suspected as much and tried the casting before posting this question, it didn't work.

Comment: What version of postgres do you have? I've checked on 9.6 and it works fine after casting types. Returns "test@test.com"

Comment: I'm running version 10. Tried your example and also `CAST()` function, didn't work.